# How to concatenate cells under a condition across columns using ARRAYFORMULA?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've found similar questions, but none with this type of condition. I need to join all cells that are dependent of another cell, separating it by comma. So, If A2:A has repeated values, concatenate all the correspondent B2:B, the dependent cells from the A2:A.

Given the sheet:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Jhon | One |
| Jhon | Two |
| Marcos | Zero |
| Monica | Two |

I need to output:

| Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- |
| Jhon | One, Two |
| Marcos | Zero |
| Monica | Two |

The cells aren't predicted values, so I can't declare "One", or "Two" as a condition in neither C or D columns.

I tried to modify this formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(", ",FILTER(B3:P3,NOT(B3:P3=""))))
```

to be something like

```
=ARRAYFORMULA((SE(A2:A=A2:A,B2:B & B2:B))
```

but it outputs an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=byrow(unique(A1:A4),lambda(z,{z,join(", ",filter(B:B,A:A=z))}))
```

[image]

Comment: What if A is also dependent of another column in the exact same way. So let's say C<A<B. How could I adapt this formula to include more dependency conditions in a tree like way? For example, If C is a date column.

Comment: it would help if you could share a sample sheet with demo data maybe and desired output so that it gives a clear picture of what is needed.

Comment: Thanks, here it is: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KgmwLvAS97vUkvGXSzeHiG69FDnLOqQtcoV2rD-cTkE/edit#gid=0

Comment: additional formula added: `=let(a,unique({A2:index(A:A,match(2,1/(A:A<>""))),B2:index(B:B,match(2,1/(B:B<>"")))}),map(index(a,,1),index(a,,2),lambda(y,z,{to_date(y),z,join(", ",filter(C:C,A:A&B:B=y&z))})))`